# Получение защищенных свойств объекта Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry

Tags: php, zend-framework

При загрузке видео на YouTube мне возвращается ответ:

```
Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry Object
(
    [_link:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Zend_Gdata_YouTube_Extension_Link Object
                (
                    [_token:protected] => 
                    [_rootElement:protected] => link
                    [_href:protected] => http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rn8jLMOF_Q&feature=youtube_gdata
                    [_rel:protected] => alternate
                    [_type:protected] => text/html
                    [_hrefLang:protected] => 
                    [_title:protected] => 
                    [_length:protected] => 
                    [_rootNamespace:protected] => atom
                    [_rootNamespaceURI:protected] => 
                    [_extensionElements:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_extensionAttributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_text:protected] => 
                    [_namespaces:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [atom] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )
)
```

Но все методы и переменные `protected`, как взять информацию из ответа?

Comment: А если добавить публичный метод, которые возвращает защищенную переменную?

Comment: не до конца понял, можно подробнее? Как можно создать метод объекте? (это же не класс)

Comment: Все, нашёл выход. Сериализовал объект и регулярным выражением взят то что надо.

Comment: @Idaho37, зачем использовать такие фееричные костыли, если можно просто почитать документацию?

Answer (score 1):

Из [документации](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.7/Zend_Gdata/YouTube/Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry.html) по классу `Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry` видно, что для каждого защищенного (protected) свойства есть свой геттер/сеттер.

Например, для получения значения свойства `_title` используется метод `getVideoTitle`.